# BABYLON.AnimationEvent doesn't behave as expected

Tags: javascript, animation, babylonjs

I need Babylon JS to fire an event at specific frames. I am using  BABYLON.AnimationEvent. But when the action function is being called, its inner variables are not properly set.

In the example below, I created a simple scene and added a box. The box will move slowly along the x axis. Every 10 frames, I would like a function to be called and "do something". In this example, it will display the frame number.

var createScene = function () {

```
// This creates a basic Babylon Scene object (non-mesh)
var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);

var box = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateBox("box", {size:10}, scene);

//setup camera
var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera", BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(-120), BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(80), 65, new BABYLON.Vector3(0, -15, 0), scene);    camera.attachControl(canvas, false);

 //setup lights
var light1 = new BABYLON.PointLight("light1", new BABYLON.Vector3(-14, 25,25), scene);
light1.intensity = 15;

var animationBox = new BABYLON.Animation("myAnim", "position", 30, BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONTYPE_VECTOR3, BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONLOOPMODE_CONSTANT);

var keys = [];

for(var i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    keys.push({
        frame: i,
        value: new BABYLON.Vector3(i/10, 0, 0)
    });

    if(i%10==0)
    {
        animationBox.addEvent(new BABYLON.AnimationEvent( i, function() { console.log( "Frame: "+i ) }, true ) );

        /*
        Expected result:
        Frame: 0
        Frame: 10
        Frame: 20
        etc.

        Actual result:
        Frame: 100
        Frame: 100
        Frame: 100
        etc.
        */
    }
}

animationBox.setKeys(keys);
box.animations.push(animationBox);

scene.beginAnimation(box, 0, 100, true);

return scene;
```

};

Expected result:
Frame: 0
Frame: 10
Frame: 20
etc.

Actual result:
Frame: 100
Frame: 100
Frame: 100
etc.

There is something I don't get. The above code can be run here:
https://playground.babylonjs.com/#B3RECS#1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello this is because you are capturing the last value of i.
You need to do a closure to capture current value:

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#B3RECS#2

(This is a general JS question and not a problem with Babylon.js)